# Replace keywords in text by comparing it with set of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Nvarchar` column in my sql table. I want to Replace/mask some words in it with *** by comparing it with set of predefined characters.

It means if my column contains words from predefined word list then I want to mask them. The predefined word list is about 400 words.

Sample DDL & DML:

```
DECLARE @Comments TABLE (id INT, comment VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES (1, 'Bob is a sales person'), (2, 'Shane is a nice guy')
DECLARE @People TABLE (personname VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @People VALUES ('Bob'), ('Mark'), ('Shane')
```

Sample Data:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id |        comment        |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | Bob is a sales person |
|  2 | Shane is a nice guy   |
+----+-----------------------+
```

Predefined Words:

```
+------------+
| personname |
+------------+
| Bob        |
| Mark       |
| Shane      |
+------------+
```

NOTE :

- please see attached images for sample data.
- I want to replace/mask with ***, if comment column contains person's name in 
  predefined words

Comment: Sample data and expected output and your try will be more helpful!

Comment: i have attched images for sample data

Comment: Images are not easy to work with hence I asked for sample data then users can copy the related data and work on it

Comment: Which database version? SQL Server 2017 introduced data masking

Comment: I have SQL Server 2016 @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1):

What if you have a Bob and a Bobby? You can't replace Bob first, or you'll end up with ***by. Here's an approach that replaces strings in reverse order of length. It's a start.

Still, if Bob is a bobsledder, you'll end up with *** is a ***sledder.

```
DECLARE @Comments TABLE (id INT, comment VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES (1, 'Bob is a sales person'), (2, 'Shane is a nice guy')
DECLARE @People TABLE (personname VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @People VALUES ('Bob'), ('Mark'), ('Shane')

DECLARE @curname VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR   
SELECT personname FROM @people ORDER BY LEN(personname) DESC, personname desc

OPEN cur  

FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
INTO @curname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN       
    UPDATE @Comments SET comment = REPLACE(comment, @curname, REPLICATE('*', LEN(@curname)))

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur   
    INTO @curname
END   
CLOSE cur;  
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM @Comments

id  comment
1   *** is a sales person
2   ***** is a nice guy
```

A couple quick mods:

1) Replace case-sensitive:

```
UPDATE @Comments SET comment = REPLACE(comment COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, @curname, REPLICATE('*', LEN(@curname)))
```

2) Replace the first instance only:

```
UPDATE @Comments SET comment = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@curname, comment) > 0   
    THEN STUFF(comment, CHARINDEX(@curname, comment), LEN(@curname), REPLICATE('*', LEN(@curname)))
    ELSE comment
    END
```

Comment: Correct and useful answer. Thanks, it helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from SQL Server 2017 you can use `STRING_AGG` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) together with `STRING_SPLIT` to break down your sentences into words, replace names with *** and then aggregate back single words into sentences:

```
select co.id, 
      string_agg(case when p.personname is null then c.value else '***' end,' ') as comment
from @Comments co
cross apply string_split(comment,' ') c
left join @People p on p.personname = c.value
group by co.id
```

Results:

[image]

If you have characters other than spaces between words you can replace them with spaces before splitting:

```
DECLARE @Comments TABLE (id INT, comment VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Comments VALUES
  (1, 'Bob (is a sales person)')
, (2, '(Shane:is-a-nice-guy)')
, (3, 'This.is(Mark),he.is-a-nice-guy,too')
DECLARE @People TABLE (personname VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @People VALUES ('Bob'), ('Mark'), ('Shane')

select co.id, 
      trim(string_agg(case when p.personname is null then c.value else '***' end,' ')) as comment
from
(
select id, replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(comment,':',' '),')',' '),'(',' '),',',' '),'.',' '),'-',' ') as comment 
from @Comments
) co
cross apply string_split(comment,' ') c
left join @People p on p.personname = c.value
group by co.id
```

Now with this kind of input:

[image]

you get this output:

[image]

Comment: Assumably cutting by blanks is not sharp enough. There might be paranthesis, dots, commas. A *whole-word* search is in most cases not trivial...

Comment: @Shnugo You are right, the first thing that comes into my mind is replacing all "unwanted" characters with space before splitting.

Comment: @Andrea My application production environment does not have SQL server 2017. in that case, what is the solution?